# atoi() doesn't like what I am doing

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a homework problem. The instructions are to code a Vigenere cipher in C.

C is not liking the follow piece of code:

```
rot = atoi(argv[1][index]) - 'A';
```

rot has been declared as an integer;

index is also an integer;

argv[1] is a string (char array) passed to C from the command-line by the user;

A bit of an explanation of the code above.

argv[1] is a string array (passed from the user at the command-line). I am using each character in this string to encode the user's message. To 'get' to each character, I am using the code above. When some branches of the code are executed, I increase index by 1 (not directly since it needs to wrap around the key if the message has more characters) to get to the next char.

I get the following error when I try to compile: http://ideone.com/pjPGlT

Comment: Post error message here, do not link to them.

Comment: `rot = argv[1][index] - 'A';` will probably suffice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with:

```
rot = argv[1][index] - 'A';
```

Also **[atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)** expects a "string", presently you are passing a character to it.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't understand the man page for atoi. I guess I am still very new to C. But your suggestion works. No reason to use atoi since rot has been declared an int and everything is, eventually, a number to C. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

`atoi()` expects a "string", really a `char *`, you are passing it a `char`.